# How to detect if two shapes collide in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code that lets the user draw a circle, square, or rectangle on a canvas in WPF.
I need to make it so the shapes will bounce off each other once the shift button has been pressed. It was easy enough to make the shapes bounce off the walls of the window, but I cannot figure out how I would make them bounce off each other.
Here is the current code:

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
    
namespace ShapeAnimator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool isFirstClick = true;
        double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
        int shapeChoice =0;
        Ellipse centerMark;
        Ellipse tempCircle = new Ellipse();
        Rectangle tempRect = new Rectangle();

        List<Circle> circles = new List<Circle>();
        List<Rect> rectangles = new List<Rect>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SquareButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            shapeChoice = 1;
        }

        private void CircleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            shapeChoice = 0;
        }

        private void RectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            shapeChoice = 2;
        }

        private void ShiftButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Shift();
        }

        public void Shift()
        {
            foreach (Circle c in circles)
            {
                c.Shift(ShapeCanvas);
            }
            foreach (Rect r in rectangles)
            {
                r.Shift(ShapeCanvas);
            }
        }

        private void ShapeCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isFirstClick)
            {
                // This is the first click
                // This is the CENTER coordinates (NOT the TOPLEFT)
                x1 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                y1 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

                if(shapeChoice == 0)
                {
                    centerMark = new Ellipse();
                    centerMark.Width = 4;
                    centerMark.Height = 4;
                    centerMark.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Add(centerMark);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(centerMark, x1 - 2);
                    Canvas.SetTop(centerMark, y1 - 2);

                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Add(tempCircle);
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 1)
                {
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Add(tempRect);
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 2)
                {
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Add(tempRect);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // THis is the second click
                double x2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                double y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

                if (shapeChoice == 0)
                {
                    double radius = Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));

                    Circle c = new Circle(x1, y1, radius);
                    c.Draw(ShapeCanvas);
                    circles.Add(c);

                    // remove the temp geometry
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Remove(tempCircle);
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Remove(centerMark);
                }
                else if(shapeChoice == 1)
                {
                    double x3 = Math.Min(x1, x2);
                    double y3 = Math.Min(y1, y2);

                    double width = Math.Max(x1, x2) - x3;
                    double height = width;

                    Rect rec = new Rect(x3, y3, width, height);
                    rec.Draw(ShapeCanvas);
                    rectangles.Add(rec);

                    // remove the temp geometry
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Remove(tempRect);
                }
                else if (shapeChoice == 2)
                {
                    double x3 = Math.Min(x1, x2);
                    double y3 = Math.Min(y1, y2);

                    double width = Math.Max(x1, x2) - x3;
                    double height = Math.Max(y1, y2) - y3;

                    Rect rec = new Rect(x3, y3, width, height);
                    rec.Draw(ShapeCanvas);
                    rectangles.Add(rec);

                    // remove the temp geometry
                    ShapeCanvas.Children.Remove(tempRect);
                }


            }

            isFirstClick = !isFirstClick;
        }

        private void ShapeCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isFirstClick)
            {
                return;
            }

            x3 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
            y3 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

            if(shapeChoice == 0)
            {
                double radius = Math.Sqrt((x3 - x1) * (x3 - x1) + (y3 - y1) * (y3 - y1));

                tempCircle.Width = radius * 2;
                tempCircle.Height = radius * 2;
                tempCircle.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                //ShapeCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
                Canvas.SetLeft(tempCircle, x1 - radius);
                Canvas.SetTop(tempCircle, y1 - radius);
            }
            else if(shapeChoice == 1)
            {
                double x2 =  Math.Min(x1, x3);
                double y2 =  Math.Min(y1, y3);

                double width = Math.Max(x1, x3) - x2;
                double height = Math.Max(y1, y3) - y2;

                tempRect.Width = width;
                tempRect.Height = width;
                tempRect.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
                Canvas.SetLeft(tempRect, x2);
                Canvas.SetTop(tempRect, y2);
            }
            else if (shapeChoice == 2)
            {
                double x2 = Math.Min(x1, x3);
                double y2 = Math.Min(y1, y3);

                double width = Math.Max(x1, x3) - x2;
                double height = Math.Max(y1, y3) - y2;

                tempRect.Width = width;
                tempRect.Height = height;
                tempRect.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
                Canvas.SetLeft(tempRect, x2);
                Canvas.SetTop(tempRect, y2);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Circle.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace ShapeAnimator
{
    internal class Circle
    {
        public Ellipse Ell = new Ellipse();
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public double Radius;
        public int DeltaX = 1;
        public int DeltaY = 1;

        public Circle(double x, double y, double r)
        {
            X = x; Y = y; Radius = r;
        }

        public void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            Ell.Width = 2 * Radius;
            Ell.Height = 2 * Radius;
            Ell.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Ell, X - Radius);
            Canvas.SetTop(Ell, Y - Radius);
            canvas.Children.Add(Ell);
        }

        public void Shift(Canvas canvas)
        {
            // Flip direction if hitting left & right walls
            if (X + Radius > canvas.ActualWidth
                || X - Radius < 0)
            {
                DeltaX = -DeltaX;
            }

            // Flip direction if hitting left & right walls
            if (Y + Radius > canvas.ActualHeight
                || Y - Radius < 0)
            {
                DeltaY = -DeltaY;
            }


            X = X + DeltaX;
            Y = Y + DeltaY;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Ell, X - Radius);
            Canvas.SetTop(Ell, Y - Radius);
        }
    }
}
```

Rect.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ShapeAnimator
{
    internal class Rect
    {
        public Rectangle Rec = new Rectangle();
        public double X;
        public double Y;
        public double Width;
        public double Height;
        public int DeltaX = 1;
        public int DeltaY = 1;

        public Rect(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            X = x; Y = y; Width = width; Height = height;
        }

        public void Draw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            Rec.Width = Width;
            Rec.Height = Height;
            if (Rec.Width == Rec.Height)
                Rec.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
            else
                Rec.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Rec, X);
            Canvas.SetTop(Rec, Y);
            canvas.Children.Add(Rec);
        }

        public void Shift(Canvas canvas)
        {

            // Flip direction if hitting left & right walls
            if (X + Width > canvas.ActualWidth
                || X < 0)
            {
                DeltaX = -DeltaX;
            }

            // Flip direction if hitting left & right walls
            if (Y + Height > canvas.ActualHeight
                || Y < 0)
            {
                DeltaY = -DeltaY;
            }

            

            X = X + DeltaX;
            Y = Y + DeltaY;
            Canvas.SetLeft(Rec, X);
            Canvas.SetTop(Rec, Y);
        }

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ShapeAnimator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ShapeAnimator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Shape Animator" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Name="ShapeCanvas" 
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                Background="Black"
                Height="380"
                MouseUp="ShapeCanvas_MouseUp"
                MouseMove="ShapeCanvas_MouseMove"
                >
            
        </Canvas>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="10">
            <Button Width="150" Height="30" Click="CircleButton_Click">Circle</Button>
            <Button Width="150" Margin="15 0" Click="SquareButton_Click">Square</Button>
            <Button Width="150" Click="RectButton_Click">Rectangle</Button>
            <Button Width="150" Click="ShiftButton_Click" Margin="15 0" >Shift</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you're running into? What have you tried to do to solve it yourself? https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: WPF isn't a physics engine. Just use something like Box2D as your model and bind the results to WPF objects to render, it's what I did to make my buttons fall to gravity and bounce against each others for fun :)

Comment: You could calculate the bounding box easily. Compare these to see if they overlap. There's then a bit of a complication for circle if it's offset so a corner of it's bounding box is it's nearest point to the corner of the other shape's bounding box. You then need to check the distance between a square or rectangle's corner and centre of the circle is less than than radius or centre of a corcle is within radiusA + radiusB of two circles.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test if two `Shape` objects intersect using the `Geometry.FillContainsWithDetail` method.

The following example shows how to drag a `Shape` while the *Shift* key is pressed. The drag is aborted as soon as the dragged `Shape` collides with another `Shape` on the `Canvas`.
You can replace the mouse drag in this example with what ever makes your shapes move. Just call `TryDetectCollision` on your `Shape` objects:

```xml
<Canvas PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Shape_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
        PreviewMouseMove="Shape_PreviewMouseMove"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Shape_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp">
  <Rectangle Width="50"
             Height="50"
             Fill="Red"
             Canvas.Left="64"
             Canvas.Top="0" />
  <Ellipse Width="50"
           Height="50"
           Fill="Yellow"
           Canvas.Left="0"
           Canvas.Top="0" />
</Canvas>
```

```cs
private Point MovingShapeDragOrigin { get; set; }
private Point MovingShapeOrigin { get; set; }
private void Shape_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Source is not Shape movingShape)
  {
    return;
  }

  movingShape.CaptureMouse();

  var canvas = sender as Canvas;
  this.MovingShapeDragOrigin = e.GetPosition(canvas);
  this.MovingShapeOrigin = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(movingShape), Canvas.GetTop(movingShape));
}


private void Shape_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (Keyboard.Modifiers is not ModifierKeys.Shift
    || Mouse.LeftButton is not MouseButtonState.Pressed)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (e.Source is not Shape movingShape)
  {
    return;
  }

  var canvas = sender as Canvas;
  Vector dragDelta = e.GetPosition(canvas) - this.MovingShapeDragOrigin;

  Point newShapePositionOffset = this.MovingShapeOrigin;
  newShapePositionOffset.Offset(dragDelta.X, dragDelta.Y);

  if (TryDetectCollision(canvas.Children.Cast<Shape>(), newShapePositionOffset, movingShape, out Shape collisionTarget))
  {
    return;
  }

  // No collision => move Shape
  Canvas.SetLeft(movingShape, newShapePositionOffset.X);
  Canvas.SetTop(movingShape, newShapePositionOffset.Y);
}

private void Shape_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Source is not Shape movingShape)
  {
    return;
  }

  movingShape.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}

private bool TryDetectCollision(IEnumerable<Shape> shapes, Point collisionSourceLocation, Shape collisionSource, out Shape collisionTarget)
{
  collisionTarget = null;

  Geometry collisionSourceGeometry = GetPositionedGeometry(collisionSource, collisionSourceLocation);

  foreach (Shape targetShape in shapes)
  {
    if (targetShape == collisionSource)
    {
      continue;
    }

    Point geometryLocation = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(targetShape), Canvas.GetTop(targetShape));
    Geometry targetGeometry = GetPositionedGeometry(targetShape, geometryLocation);

    IntersectionDetail intersectionDetail = collisionSourceGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(targetGeometry);
    bool hasCollision = intersectionDetail is not IntersectionDetail.Empty and not IntersectionDetail.NotCalculated;
    if (hasCollision)
    {
      collisionTarget = targetShape;
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```